# How to add a new tick to the autogenerated ticks in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to add just a tick to the existing autogenerated ticks, how can I do it ?
This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYFV5/6/). I want to add tick `100` to the existing generated tick series. Can such a hack be done in flot ?

Comment: Do you mean to start the y axis from 100?

Comment: No, it starts with 0, but I want to add additional tick 100, auto generated is [0,200,400,600,800,1000]. I want to push 100 to the series so it will be [0,100,200,400,600,800,1000]. I am trying to plot a threshold line 100 on the graph.

Comment: can someone explain me why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping this would be possible using the `hooks` [functionality in flot](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#hooks) but unfortunatly the ticks are generated and then the labels are added without any hooks in between.

So...

Your best bet would be to steal flots automatic tick generator, modify it to do what you want and then add it as the tick function in your options.

```
customTickGen = function (axis) {

    /* BEGIN STOLEN FLOT METHOD */    

    var ticks = [],
        start = axis.tickSize * Math.floor(axis.min / axis.tickSize),
        i = 0,
        v = Number.NaN,
        prev;

    do {
        prev = v;
        v = start + i * axis.tickSize;
        ticks.push(v);
        ++i;
    } while (v < axis.max && v != prev);

    /* END OF STOLEN FLOT CODE */

    /* Now find the spot and put a 100 in */
    for (var i = 0; i < ticks.length - 1; i++){
        if (ticks[i] < 100 && ticks[i+1] > 100){
            ticks.splice(i,0,100);
            break;
        }
    }                    
    return ticks;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ydXN4/1/).